# Android detecting hardware zoom button

Tags: android, android-camera

Does anyone know if there exists a way to programmatically check if a hardware zoom button is present on the device (like for the Samsung Galaxy Camera, for example)?

Thanks

Comment: My Samsung Galaxy (Note II) zooms with the volume controls. Does those count? If so, every phone and tablet has them.

Comment: What is exactly "hardware zoom button" ?

Comment: @g00dy, there is HW zoom button: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wr4nljdbkzz25wy/nexusae0_Galaxy_camera_B_front_thumb1.jpg

Comment: @Keyser, volume controls on Samsung Galaxy use KEYCODE_ZOOM_OUT and KEYCODE_ZOOM_IN key codes, while volume control on other devices use KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP and KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN key codes. I need to check if there is control which use KEYCODE_ZOOM_OUT and KEYCODE_ZOOM_IN key codes available on device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It possible to detect HW zoom buttons via `android.view.KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ZOOM_IN)` method.

Comment: This worked great for the Samsung Galaxy Camera 2. I was able to handle zoom in/out events properly.